# MySQL return column if username part of disabled group

Tags: mysql, sql, radius

I have two tables as below

radcheck

```
+----+-------------------+--------------------+----+--------+
| id | username          | attribute          | op | value  |
+----+-------------------+--------------------+----+--------+
|  1 | userA             | Cleartext-Password | := | Apass  |
|  2 | userB             | Cleartext-Password | := | Bpass  |
|  3 | DC:9F:DB:xx:xx:xx | Auth-Type          | := | Accept |
|  4 | userC             | Cleartext-Password | := | Cpass  |
+----+-------------------+--------------------+----+--------+
```

radusergroup

```
+----------+------------+----------+
| username | groupname  | priority |
+----------+------------+----------+
| userA    | daily-plan |        1 |
| userA    | disabled   |        0 |
| userB    | quota-plan |        1 |
| userC    | disabled   |        0 |
| userC    | try        |        1 |
+----------+------------+----------+
```

I use the below query to return results which lists usernames that are not part of disabled group but i would like to return another column in results called disabled with value as 1 if part of disabled group and 0 if not:

```
SELECT c.id, c.username, c.value, g.groupname
FROM radcheck c LEFT JOIN
     radusergroup g
     USING (username)
WHERE attribute = 'Cleartext-Password' AND
      groupname <> 'disabled';
```

I tried multiple ways using triple left joins using below query but they dont seem to work, the groupname column in result is always of the first groupname found in radusergroup table:

```
SELECT c.id, c.username, c.value, g.groupname, (disabled.username IS NOT NULL) AS disabled
FROM radcheck c LEFT JOIN
     radusergroup g
     ON c.username = g.username LEFT JOIN
     radusergroup disabled
     ON disabled.username = c.username AND
        disabled.groupname = 'disabled'
WHERE (c.username = g.username) AND
      attribute = 'Cleartext-Password'
GROUP BY c.username;
```

the above outputs:

```
+----+----------+-------+------------+----------+
| id | username | value | groupname  | disabled |
+----+----------+-------+------------+----------+
|  1 | userA    | Apass | daily-plan |        1 |
|  2 | userB    | Bpass | quota-plan |        0 |
|  4 | userC    | Cpass | disabled   |        1 |
+----+----------+-------+------------+----------+
```

Comment: `Cleartext-Password` ?  storing clear text passwords in a database is a absolute **no go**..

Comment: i know but this is just for testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to extend your query with an `EXISTS` and a correlated subquery.

```
SELECT c.id,
       c.username,
       c.value,
       g.groupname,
       EXISTS (SELECT *
                      FROM radusergroup g2
                           WHERE g2.username = c.username
                                 AND g2.groupname = 'disabled') disabled
       FROM radcheck c
            LEFT JOIN radusergroup g
                      ON g.username = c.username
       WHERE c.attribute = 'Cleartext-Password'
             AND g.groupname <> 'disabled';
```

That assumes, that your first query is fine. I couldn't tell from your post if it is OK, since it will return a row for each non disabled group a user is in, i.e. probably more than one row per user. If that is an issue too, you can use a second `EXISTS` in an analog way with `g2.groupname <> 'disabled'` and removing the left join.

---

Edit: If you only want flags if a user in a disabled and/or a not disabled group:

```
SELECT c.id,
       c.username,
       c.value,
       EXISTS (SELECT *
                      FROM radusergroup g2
                           WHERE g2.username = c.username
                                 AND g2.groupname = 'disabled') disabled,
       EXISTS (SELECT *
                      FROM radusergroup g2
                           WHERE g2.username = c.username
                                 AND g2.groupname <> 'disabled') not_disabled
       FROM radcheck c
       WHERE c.attribute = 'Cleartext-Password';
```

Comment: this looks fine and the user can only be in one other group other than disabled as far as i have designed the portal so chances of same user in more than 2 groups isnt possible (disabled and the plan group)

Comment: Can you elaborate on what do you mean by use a second exists and remove the left join coz if I remove the left join won't it stop returning the group

Comment: @xbipin: See the edit. If it helps you, you might also consider accepting and/or up voting.

Comment: well i need the groupname as well so ill accept the first answer

Answer (score 0):

You may try CASE STATEMENT in SQL Query. Like below:

```
SELECT c.id, c.username, c.value, g.groupname, (CASE
    WHEN g.groupname = 'disabled' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END) AS 'disabled' FROM radcheck c LEFT JOIN radusergroup g USING (username) WHERE attribute = 'Cleartext-Password';
```